# Show only one Shipping rate based on cart amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Using Woocommerce in WordPress
I am trying to find a way to use 2 shipping charges:
If a customer order is less than n amount then shipping is standard x amount
If a customer order is more than n amount then shipping is reduced to x amount
I also need to hide the standard if the order qualifies for reduced shipping.

Currently woocommerce displays both shipping charges if the order qualifies for reduced shipping

Any ideas how i can resolve this please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried the code of my answer … just wondering some feed back on it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_package_rates`** action hook that will show only one shipping rate based on the cart amount limit:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_sshipping_rate_based_on_cart_amount', 100 );
function hide_sshipping_rate_based_on_cart_amount( $rates ) {

    // HERE define the limit amount to switch of shipping rate (integer)
    $amout_limit = 600;
    // Cart total amount (integer)
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    // Set below your 2 Rate ID slugs
    if( $cart_total >= $amout_limit )
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:12'] ); // Removes the LOWER Rate 
    else
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:8'] ); // Removes the HIGHER Rate

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Comment: Hi LoicSorry i did try that but it did not work. I ended up finding a plug in to allow 2 shipping charges, just trying to find a way now where we can split the country into two parts but use the same country code. Example England (GB) Scotland (GB)

Comment: On which woocommerce version are you doing that? This is really working. You have just to set the 2 correct slugs for lower and higher rates … If needed you can contact me on Skype chat (my ID is `marsloic` ) …